# Generated SQL query syntax with Oracle are old

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am using Hibernate 3.2.5. When I use a `JOIN` I can see that the sql query generated by the Hibernate are the syntax prior to the Oracle 9i release. The queries are having (+) symbols to denote the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` rather than using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and so on.

For this criteria:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Dept.class).createAlias("empMap","id",CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN).add(Restrictions.eq("deptId", new Integer(6)));
```

This is the SQL query generated:

```
select this_.DEPT_ID as DEPT1_1_1_, this_.DEPT_NAME as DEPT2_1_1_, id1_.DEPT_ID as DEPT2_3_, id1_.EMP_ID as EMP1_3_, id1_.EMP_ID as formula0_3_, id1_.EMP_ID as EMP1_0_0_, id1_.DEPT_ID as DEPT2_0_0_, id1_.EMP_NAME as EMP3_0_0_, id1_.AGE as AGE0_0_, id1_.SEX as SEX0_0_ from dept this_, emp id1_ where this_.DEPT_ID=id1_.DEPT_ID(+) and this_.DEPT_ID=?
```

My Queston is:

1) Why the queries are having old syntax? If I use Hibernate 4.0 or latest one then will it generate the new syntax SQL queries?

2) How to perform `Outer Join` in this case? I can see options for `LEFT JOIN` and `FULL JOIN` but can't see anything for `RIGHT JOIN`

**EDIT**

Q. 2 It was a typo mistake, its `RIGHT JOIN`

Please let me know about these.

Regards,

Comment: Which Oracle dialect are you using?

Comment: DB is oracle 10g, dialect in cfg file: `<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>`

Comment: You should use `Oracle10gDialect`. See Tom Anderson's answer

Comment: Thanks, I got it. And what abt the 2nd Q ? How to achieve RIght Join? Please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [current Hibernate source code](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/), then you'll see that there are a number of different [SQL dialects](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/tree/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect) for Oracle:

- [8](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/OracleDialect.java) - deprecated in favour of 8i
- [8i](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/Oracle8iDialect.java) - generates the `(+)` syntax
- [9](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/Oracle9Dialect.java) - deprecated in favour of either 9i or 10g
- [9i](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/Oracle9iDialect.java) - generates the `(+)` syntax, with the comment *Specifies to not use "ANSI join syntax" because 9i does not seem to properly handle it in all cases*
- [10g](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/Oracle10gDialect.java) - generates ANSI joins

So, the only way to get ANSI join syntax is to use the 10g dialect. I don't know if that existed in 3.2.5, or if it did, whether the version of it there generates ANSI joins, but it's the only thing you can try.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It has solved my first problem. Can you please provide some inputs on the second Q ?

Comment: Sadly, i don't believe it is possible to do right outer joins in either Hibernate or JPA criteria. As an aside, if you have two questions, you should make two separate posts here, rather than putting them both in one.

Answer (score 0):

Ad 2) If you have "left join" and "full join" (and, as I guess, "right join") options, then you can perform outer joins. These are the three existing types of an outer join. There is no such thing as a "pure" outer join.

Comment: I think right join may always be replaced with left join by reversing the order of tables.